# mysql error in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry to ask such a basic question, but I cant for the life of me spot the error here as far as I can see everything is correct. Yet I get the error, perhaps I need a pair of fresh eyes to have a look

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE event_id = '1243'' at line 1 in INSERT INTO expiredEvents
>   (event_id,sport_type,tournament,round,team1,team2,venue,event_date)
>   values ('1243','Rugby','Super15','3','Waratahs','Sharks','Allianz
>   Stadium','') WHERE event_id = '1243'

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO expiredEvents 

(event_id,sport_type,tournament,round,team1,team2,venue,event_date) 

values ('$id','$sport','$trnmnt','$rnd','$t1','$t2','$ven','$eDate') 

WHERE event_id = '$id'"
```

Comment: Where is in INSERT statement not allowed. see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html). What are you triing to so?

Comment: Where clause is allowed only when you do `insert into select from`

Comment: @DeepakPawar im learning what is wrong if someone upvoted my question? im new to the community no need to be rude...thanks

Comment: @gekkogurru: you want to insert new record (insert into without where), or update the current one?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty the `WHERE` clause in the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) belongs to the `SELECT` **subquery**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `WHERE` clause in the correct syntax of the [`INSERT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html).

Depending on what you want to achieve, choose one of the following.

#### Insert a new row, don't bother if another one having the same `event_id` already exists

```
INSERT INTO expiredEvents
    (event_id, sport_type, tournament, round, team1, team2, venue, event_date) 
VALUES
    ('$id', '$sport', '$trnmnt', '$rnd', '$t1', '$t2', '$ven', '$eDate')
```

If `event_id` is an `UNIQUE INDEX` of table `expiredEvents`, this query fails if another record having `event_id = '$id'` already exists.

Assuming `event_id` is the `PK` of the table, keep reading.

#### Insert a new row but only if it does not already exists

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO expiredEvents
    (event_id, sport_type, tournament, round, team1, team2, venue, event_date) 
VALUES
    ('$id', '$sport', '$trnmnt', '$rnd', '$t1', '$t2', '$ven', '$eDate')
```

The `IGNORE` keyword turns the errors into warnings and the query completes successfully but it does not insert the row if another one having `event_id = '$id'` already exists.

#### Inserts a row if it does not exist or update the existing one, if it exists

```
INSERT INTO expiredEvents
    (event_id, sport_type, tournament, round, team1, team2, venue, event_date) 
VALUES
    ('$id', '$sport', '$trnmnt', '$rnd', '$t1', '$t2', '$ven', '$eDate') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    sport_type=VALUES(sport_type), round=round+1, event_date=NOW()
```

If the row does not exist, this query insert it using the values from the `VALUES` clause. If the row already exists then it uses the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to know how to update it. There are three fields modified in this query:

- `sport_type=VALUES(sport_type)` - the value of column `sport_type` is updated using the value provided in the query for column `sport_type` (`VALUES(sport_type)`, which is `'$sport'`);
- `round=VALUES(round)+1` - the value of column `round` is updated using its current value plus 1 (`round+1`); the value provided in the `VALUES` clause is not used;
- `event_date=NOW()` - the value of column `event_date` is modified using the value returned by the function `NOW()`; both the old value and the one provided in the `VALUES` clause of the query are ignored.

This is just an example, you put there whatever expressions you need to update the existing row.

#### Completely replace the existing row with a new one

```
REPLACE INTO expiredEvents
    (event_id, sport_type, tournament, round, team1, team2, venue, event_date) 
VALUES
    ('$id', '$sport', '$trnmnt', '$rnd', '$t1', '$t2', '$ven', '$eDate')
```

The [`REPLACE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. It first `DELETE`s the row having `event_id = '$id'` (if any) then `INSERT`s a new row. It is functionally equivalent with `DELETE FROM expiredEvents WHERE event_id = '$id'` followed by the first query exposed above in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE keyword is not allowed in INSERT INTO / VALUES
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Elaborate what you would like to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use where in insert statment, instead of just get the data from the respective tables which contains the exact records and insert necessary rows alone by adding your conditions in the select statement of that query.
Here is the simple one to resolve your error,

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO expiredEvents 

(event_id,sport_type,tournament,round,team1,team2,venue,event_date) 

SELECT event_id,sport_type,tournament,round,team1,team2,venue,event_date from events WHERE event_id = '$id'"
```